# PIR sensor project (LHI778) with Arduino Nano - sensor doesn't react

Tags: sensor

[image]

When I give voltage to the circuit, the LED lights, but the sensor doesn't work. What  should I change in the circuit?

Comment: Have you got an oscilloscope?

Comment: @KadirYilmaz:  You have the signal passing through the Nano.  Have the Nano print the value of D2 and D3 so that you can see if the sensor is working and if you are properly switching the output.

Comment: :O wow - I'm almost speechless! Here's someone who's not trying to run a 741 from a single 5V supply!!! ;)